# how to get latest data from relation table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm working on a project using Laravel 10.

The goal is to get the latest `tgl_pengajuan` of each customers from inside `PenawaranController.php` like this:

```
customer_id | name  | email           | latest_penawaran_by_cust
----------------------------------------------------------------
1           | david | david@gmail.com | 2023-12-20 01:00:00
2           | alan  | alan1@gmail.com | null
```

But instead, this is the data structure that I'm getting when I use `dd($penawaran[0]->customer);`:

```
App\Models\Customer {
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "customers"
  .. // other attributes
  #attributes: array:9 [
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "david"
    "email" => "david@gmail.com"
    .. // other columns
    "latestPenawaranByCust" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {
      "items: array:1 {
        0 => App\Models\Customer {
          #connection: "mysql"
          #table: "customers"
          .. // other attributes
          #attributes: array:8 [
            "id" => 1
            "name" => "david"
            "email" => "david@gmail.com"
            .. // the rest is the same as above but without "lastPenawaranByCust"
```

These are my tables:

`customers` (simplified)

```
id | name  | email
--------------------------------
1  | david | david@gmail.com
2  | alan  | alan1@gmail.com
```

`barangs` (simplified)

```
id | name           | stok | harga
-----------------------------------
1  | laptop 14 inch | 100  | 150
2  | USB cable      | 50   | 10
```

`penawarans` (simplified)

```
id | customer_id | tgl_pengajuan       | updated_at
----------------------------------------------------
1  | 1           | 2023-12-19 00:00:00 | 2023-12-15 05:00:00
2  | 1           | 2023-12-20 01:00:00 | 2023-12-17 07:00:00
```

`detail_penawaran` (simplified)

```
id | penawaran_id | barang_id | qty | harga
--------------------------------------------
1  | 1            | 1         | 11  | 200
2  | 1            | 2         | 22  | 20
3  | 2            | 1         | 12  | 210
```

This is my code:

`Models/Penawaran.php`

```
    public function detail_penawaran()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(DetailPenawaran::class);
    }

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
    }
```

`Models/DetailPenawaran.php`

```
    public function penawaran()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Penawaran::class);
    }

    public function barang()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Barang::class);
    }
```

`Models/Customer.php`

```
    public function penawarans()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Penawaran::class, 'customer_id');
    }

    public function latestPenawaranByCust()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Penawaran::class, 'customer_id')->latest('updated_at');
    }
```

`PenawaranController.php`

```
        $penawaran = Penawaran::where('id', '=', $id)->get();

        if ($penawaran) {
            $tglPenawaranByCust = Customer::where('id', '=', $penawaran[0]->customer->id)
                ->with(['latestPenawaranByCust' => function($query) {
                    $query->whereNotNull('updated_at');
                }])
                ->orderBy('nama', 'ASC')
                ->get();
            $penawaran[0]['customer']['latestPenawaranByCust'] = $tglPenawaranByCust;
        }
        dd($penawaran[0]->customer);
```

Can someone help me with this? I'm very new to Laravel so I'm still having a hard time understanding the Eloquent ORM concept. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: does your table `penawarans` have `updated_at` column? I did not see it.

Comment: @FaizanAli yes, it does. the table structure I wrote is the simplified version and since `updated_at` is auto-generated by laravel's migration template (`$table->timestamps()`) I thought I didn't need to explicitly write it.. also, it was already near midnight here and I have been struggling with this problem for days so I'm sorry if my concentration and willpower is very low

Comment: I have already accepted it and configured it.

Comment: thank you for your concern, but I think I've just figured it out too.. I'm using the Many to Many relationship concept to solve this. but is it ok if I contact you some other time to ask about other programming related things when I get stuck again?